Pybind11 CMake configuration on ubuntu with multi .h/.cpp files and dependencies
I'm trying do compile a pybind11 module called CAVSim and import it into python.
Everything goes right on Windows (with VS2022), but I've got stuck on ubuntu with cmake.
What I expect to do
Although the codes of pybind11 module depends on Eigen and Boost Geometry,
I hope the module, compiled on ubuntu with cmake, can be imported in any other computer:

with ubuntu system
with python and NumPy installed (same with compiling version)
without any c++ dependencies installed (Pybind11, Eigen and Boost)

Where I stuck in
Here's my c++ files:
CAVSim
├─include
│  ├─algos
│  │  ├─utils
│  │  │  ├─LCMap.h
│  │  │  └─...
│  │  ├─xxx.h
│  │  └─...
│  ├─xxx.h
│  └─...
│  (Complex, multi-level, highly isomerized document tree, with only .h files in it)
├─src
│  ├─algos
│  │  ├─utils
│  │  │  ├─LCMap.cpp
│  │  │  └─...
│  │  ├─xxx.cpp
│  │  └─...
│  ├─xxx.cpp
│  ├─...
│  └─PySim.cpp
│  (With only .cpp files in it)
└─CMakeLists.txt

The PySim.cpp file includes my definition about the pybind modules, which wraps the classes and functions declared in .h files like LCMap.h in include folder, and defined in files in src folder.
My CMakeLists file: (I'm new to cmake. Maybe I've missed something here? )
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(CAVSim LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY /home/isuzu/CAVSim2.3.l/PyCAVSim/PyCAVSim/core/)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY /home/isuzu/CAVSim2.3.l/PyCAVSim/PyCAVSim/core/)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY /home/isuzu/CAVSim2.3.l/PyCAVSim/PyCAVSim/core/)
# I want to output the .so library to this path
set(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE /home/isuzu/anaconda3/envs/CAVSim39/bin/python)
# The version of Python I expect
include_directories("/home/isuzu/cpp-packages/eigen-3.4.0")
include_directories("/home/isuzu/cpp-packages/boost_1_80_0/")
# boost and Eigen was used in the c++ codes

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)

include_directories("./include/")
file(GLOB_RECURSE CAVSimSrc ./src/*.cpp)
pybind11_add_module(CAVSim ${CAVSimSrc})

The bug is that, the library goes well when I import it on the computer I compile it(ubuntu 22.04).
But when I copied only the .so file to another computer(also ubuntu 22.04) without cmake and any c++ dependencies, I got the error below when I tried to import it:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Simulator' from 'PyCAVSim.core' (/home/kagami/PyCAVSim./PyCAVSim/core/__init__.py)

what I've tried
Because Win|VS-compile-Win-run and ubuntu|cmake-compile-ubuntu-run(on the compiling machine) didn't caused any bug, I guess my CMakeLists is not right, which makes something was not included or linked to the output .so file.
I tried with pybind11_add_module(CAVSim STATIC ${CAVSimSrc}), but it caused the ubuntu|cmake-compile-ubuntu-run on the compiling machine also met the same error.
